# Can we take $A_n$'s to be increasing?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space. Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be two measures on $\mathcal A.$ Let $\mathcal C$ be the subcollection of $\mathcal A$ consisting of all those $A \in \mathcal A$ such that $\mu (A) = 0.$ Now let $s: = \sup \left \{\lambda (A)\ |\ A \in \mathcal C \right \}.$ Then it is clear that there exists a sequence $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $\mathcal C$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lambda (A_n) = s.$

$\textbf {Question}$ $:$ Can we take $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ to be increasing?

Our instructor says that WLOG we can always assume that $A_n$'s are increasing. But I didn't get the point. Would anybody please explain it a bit?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_n=\bigcup_{i\le n}A_i$. Then trivially the sequence $(B_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing and has $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B_i=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$, and since the union of finitely many $\mu$-null sets is $\mu$-null we have $B_i\in \mathcal{C}$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Since $B_n$'s are increasing it clearly follows that $$\lambda \left (\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \right ) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lambda (B_n) \geq \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lambda (A_n) = s.$$ But how does it follow that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lambda (B_n) \leq s\ $?

Comment: @Anacardium Since each $B_n$ is in $\mathcal{C}$ we have $\sup\{\lambda(B_n): n\in\mathbb{N}\}\le\sup\{\lambda(X): X\in\mathcal{C}\}$.

Comment: Oh! I see. It's too easy. Sorry for questioning.

Comment: @Anacardium Not at all, questioning is always the right thing to do!